# Using Mamp or another package vs manually enabling PHP and installing MySQL on Mac 10.6

Tags: php, mysql, macos

What are the benefits of installing mamp or another package vs enabling php in httpd.conf and manually installing mysql? I am really not sure of which option is better and would love some info.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAMP and other packages are usually pre-configured and come with other tools like phpMyAdmin, SQLite Manager, SSL, code optimizers. If you think you're handy enough to do what others have done, go ahead. But it'll save you a lot of time and trouble by grabbing what's already available.

Answer (score 0):

I've used MAMP for over two years now and I love it.

For me, I didn't want to configure PHP and MySQL with Apache. On my old computer I installed MySQL and then phpMyAdmin and had *a lot of fun* trying to get it all working. (But I'm not good with terminal and bash commands)

I installed MAMP on my new computer just because it does all the work for me. When I want to debug a php script, I just fire up my local server and make a few changes.

Answer (score 0):

Imo, MAMP/WAMP = Easy get up and go in a development environment. 
If you are running a business critical app, you may be better off with a LAMP stack